# Debugging Celery with VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, celery, vscode-debugger

I am using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for web-developing with framework Django. There is no questions for debugging Django, but when i try to use [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) - debugger dosn't stop at breakpoints. I use this configuration for run Celery and Celery Beat:

```
{
    "name": "Beat",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "pythonPath": "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/bin/python",
    "program": "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/bin/celery",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "-A",
        "bgp",
        "beat",
        "-l",
        "info"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Celery",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "pythonPath": "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/bin/python",
    "program": "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/bin/celery",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "-A",
        "bgp",
        "worker",
        "-l",
        "info",
        "-Q",
        "ssh",
        "--concurrency=1",
    ]
},
```

When i run Celery - i get this traceback:

```
[2018-11-29 13:18:34,112: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: RuntimeError('already started',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/base.py", line 131, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/prefork.py", line 112, in on_start
    **self.options)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 432, in __init__
    super(AsynPool, self).__init__(processes, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1007, in __init__
    self._create_worker_process(i)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 449, in _create_worker_process
    return super(AsynPool, self)._create_worker_process(i)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1116, in _create_worker_process
    w.start()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 124, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/context.py", line 333, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/popen_fork.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/popen_fork.py", line 72, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 488, in new_fork
    _on_forked_process()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 56, in _on_forked_process
    pydevd.settrace_forked()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1723, in settrace_forked
    patch_multiprocessing=True,
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1488, in settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1536, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 484, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/pydevd_hooks.py", line 125, in <lambda>
    _start_client = (lambda h, p: start_client(daemon, h, p))
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/pydevd_hooks.py", line 71, in start_client
    sock, start_session = daemon.start_client((host, port))
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 208, in start_client
    with self.started():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 109, in started
    self.start()
  File "/home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 144, in start
    raise RuntimeError('already started')
RuntimeError: already started
[2018-11-29 13:18:34,158: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://project:**@127.0.0.1:5672/project
[2018-11-29 13:18:34,210: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-11-29 13:18:35,292: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-11-29 13:18:35,353: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/MyName/job/MyProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:200: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2018-11-29 13:18:35,354: INFO/MainProcess] celery@MyName-vm ready..
```

Celery is working fine. But when i put breakpoint into any task - Celery thread dosn't stop on it. How can i fix it?
My Celery version: celery[redis]==4.2.0

Comment: I'm not [alone](https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1046)

Comment: I need this to be figured out as well.

Answer (score 51):

You can try adding "-P solo" into args of Celery configuration.
Refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1046

Here is my Celery configuration. It is working properly for me.

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Celery",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "celery",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "-A",
            "tsbc",
            "worker",
            "-l",
            "info",
            "-P",
            "solo",
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, it saved my many hours of manual debugging. Thank you very much @Kevin Z. Li.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but if you are installing your code with a `python setup.py install` be sure you are setting breakpoints in the site-packages version not your project's working directory or the breakpoints won't trigger.

Answer (score 6):

This my configuration, works just fine.

```
{
  "name": "Python: Django Shell",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
  "args": [
    "shell"
  ],
  "django": true
},
{
  "name": "Python: Celery Workers",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "module": "celery",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
  "args": ["-A", "yourproject", "worker", "-l", "debug", "-Q", "queueName"]
```

}

Answer (score 6):

I figured out a way that uses debugpy in VS Code to have a better debugging experience than the Celery pdb.
I use docker-compose, but even if you don't you can still use the idea.

So first start up you celery with debugpy

```
  celery:
    command:
      [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:6900 -m celery -A backend.celery worker -l info",
      ]
    ports:
      - 6900:6900
```

Then here is the launch.json

```
{
    "name": "Celery: Remote Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "connect": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 6900
    },
    "pathMappings": [{
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "/app"
    }],
    // "preLaunchTask": "docker-compose up",
    "django": true,
},
```

That's it, enjoy debugging!
You can set break points and evaluate variables as you usually do.
[image]

I have a [post](https://miaoz2001.medium.com/debug-celery-in-a-docker-compose-container-with-vs-code-2b1d7d5eef99) about this for more

Comment: I tried to follow the approach and the debugger pauses at the breakpoints perfectly. But when I disconnect the debugger, it doesn’t get disconnected even though the debug subprocesses are terminated

Comment: Disconnecting(detach) won't stop the celery, you could just `docker-compose stop/restart celery`  (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: Is it a constraint from debugpy / vscode ? Also, the hot reload doesn’t seem to be working with Celery. It works fine for the app without —noreload —nothreading.

Comment: hot reload is a feature of django, not celery. If your code changes, you have to restart manually the celery

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me where I don't want to install an additional debugger. Also putting "-P solo" in the arguments is not required as pointed in one of the answer. Here's the configuration which worked for me

The only two things to take care of are

1. **cwd** or current working directory should be the same folder as where you run celery from in the terminal. In my case, clickserver is the django folder which contains celery.py so I will run it above that folder
2. **PYTHONPATH** should be the same folder as cwd.

It should work seamlessly

```
 "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python: Celery",
                "type": "python",
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/clickstream-server/django/clickserver",
                "request": "launch",
                "module": "celery",
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "env": {
                    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/clickstream-server/django/clickserver"
                  },
                "args": [
                    "-A",
                    "clickserver",
                    "worker",
                    "-l",
                    "info",
                ]
            },
```